# How to persist text after a form submit (how to not delete itself after submit?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, save, save-as

How do I save and repopulate text in a text box? Each time I click save, the old text is removed from the text input box, it should not be removed.

I want to make an online editor and I need to be able to save the current text without removing the text from the textarea box after saving it.

```js
var types = [
      {"extension": ".html", "name": "HTML"},
      {"extension": ".txt", "name": "Plain Text"},
      {"extension": ".js", "name": "Javascript"},
      {"extension": ".css", "name": "CSS"},
    ];
types.forEach(function(type) {
  $opt = $("<option>").attr("value", type.extension).text(type.name)
  $("#saveas").append($opt)
});

function SaveAsType() {
  console.log($("#saveas").val());

  {
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {
      type: "text/plain"
    });
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value + "" + $("#saveas").val();

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    downloadLink.click();
  }

}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="inputTextToSave" name="inputTextToSave" rows="10" cols="70" placeholder="Type your text here:"></textarea>
    <br>
    <textarea id="inputFileNameToSaveAs" rows="1" cols="70" placeholder=" Filename Save As " style="resize:none;"></textarea>
    <br>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    Save as
    <select id="saveas">
      <option value="">Defoult ´´ TXT ´´ file or type your own file type</option>
      <option value=".html">´´ HTML ´´ file</option>
      <option value=".js">´´ JS ´´ file</option>
      <option value=".css">´´ CSS ´´ file</option>
      <option value=".txt">´´ TXT ´´ file</option>
    </select><button onclick="SaveAsType();">Save</button>
```

Comment: cookies ?? HTML5 Local Storage ??

Comment: Thank you for shorten up my answer. I guess my English is not that good when talking about codes. Thank you... @SWPhantom

Comment: Thank you, funny though after a lot of trying to find the answer to this I found it on my own. But I will keep the question online for those who may have the same question or problem and will not know how to solve it. It is silly how simple the solution was and how I have over seen it. @br3t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having this question a longer time on the page, I found the answer myself on my own. It was actually pretty simple solution.

I just changed the:

```
<button onclick="SaveAsType();">Save</button>
```

into

```
<input type="button" onClick="SaveAsType();" value=" Save ">
```

And WALLAH, now text is kept after saving in the textarea without having it deleted.

**NOTE:** I will keep the question online for those who may have the same question or problem and will not know how to solve it. It is silly how simple the solution was and how I have over seen it.